# How can you invoke db:migrate:up as part of another rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rails-migrations, rake-task

From the command line, I can run

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20120123160700
```

This will migrate up to that specific version.

I want to be able to migrate up (but not beyond a specific version) from a rake task, preferably using db:migrate:up.

I've tried the following and put the error messages below:

```
Rake::Task['db:migrate:up VERSION=20120123160700'].invoke
```

Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate:up VERSION=20111208105833'

```
Rake::Task['db:migrate:up'].invoke('VERSION=20120123160700')
```

VERSION is required

```
Rake.application.invoke_task("db:migrate:up[VERSION=20120123160700]"
```

VERSION is required

```
Rake.application.invoke_task("db:migrate:up[VERSION=20120123160700]"
```

Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate:up VERSION=20111208105833'

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably not the better solution but it should work. You can do this :

```
  ActiveRecord::Migrator.run(:up, ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_path, 20120123160700)
  Rake::Task["db:schema:dump"].invoke if ActiveRecord::Base.schema_format == :ruby
```

You can see the source here : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/621df2a1ec01b77f7b052b3571f3c696f0443fea/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake at line 163.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do:

```
ENV["VERSION"] = "20120123160700"
Rake::Task["db:migrate:up"].invoke
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
system("rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20120123160700")
```

(I am unclear as to whether or not that works on Windows though, as it uses Kernel#system).

Comment: This worked, but I'm going for the other solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/11615715/1235816 because it doesn't run the schema dump every time I call it.

Comment: No problem. Glad you found a solution!